# Move someone from one list to another

Tags: word-usage

> Can I **move** you from this list to the other list?

A few kids were making a list. (On paper) They'd written the name of a child on one list but later on wanted to strike his name off this list and write it down on the other list. Is the use of "move" fine here? I mean they couldn't actually "move" the name as in a computer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

"Move" seems perfectly idiomatic. More common might be *transfer*:

> Can I *transfer* you from this list to the other list?

In my line of work, I deal with waiting lists, and this is the term most frequently used.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it would have been more accurate to say

> Can I move your name from this list to the other list?

But considering the context, I would expect the statement to be understood without the clarification.

The person is describing the end result.  Yes, it is really "remove your name from here" and "add your name to here"; but, in the overall context of things, it is similar to the idea that the name transferred itself between the lists.

Comment: I suggest that it would be, not more accurate, but more pedantic to use **your name** instead of **you** as that's how people speak and the meaning must be clear to any English speaker. In written English, **your name** might be more likely. However, both options are perfectly grammatical and idiomatic.

Comment: @RonaldSole I only called it more accurate because the name is being moved, not the person; but, I fully understand what you said and it makes a lot of sense to me.